# Android GCM notification : no title

Tags: php, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, payload

I'am building an Android app and currently working on notifications. I'm using the Google Cloud Messaging service, for which I wrote the following PHP code :

```
<?php
define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'blablabla');
$registrationIds = array($this->deviceId);

$data = array
(
    'title' => 'My Title',
    'message' => 'My message',
    'subtitle' => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText' => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'data' => $data
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When i execute this php file, I receive the notification on my Android device, as you can see on the following screenshot. The message text is ok.
[android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnkgf.jpg)
But the problem is that the notification's title is not 'My Title' as I wrote in the payload, but 'GCM Message' (looks like default GCM title).
Tried a lot of different things but didn't figured it out.

Any ideas where I'm wrong ? Thanks

-------- SOLUTION --------

I had totaly forgot this has to be handled on the android side... The solution was to custom the sendNotification() method in MyGcmListenerService to handle extra data :

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Thanks for answers !

Comment: post your android approach ?

Comment: I don't have anything special on the Android side, I thought the app would handle the notification by itself. Do I have to write specific code to handle the notification title and other parameters ?

Comment: yea if u want to set the name of title :)

Comment: Good to know ! Thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to set a custom notification title you should create your own notification inside onMessageReceived(String form, Bundle data) method of GcmListenerService class...what i did to create a custom notification is described in the following code:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setContentTitle(data.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title)))
                .setContentText(data.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_body)))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        int mNotificationId = 001;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, nBuilder.build());
  }
 }
```

where in setContentTitle you set your custom notification title.